# Angular Material - Removing Whitespaces

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

As you can see on this snippet where Angular Material is not injected, the `<div>` tag inherits the background color of the body.

```js
angular.module("Test", []);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>



<body ng-app="Test" style="background-color: red;">
  {{1+1}}
  <div style="margin-top: 700px;">
    bar
  </div>
</body>
```

However, the below snippet has Angular Material injected into the Angular Module. Now the `<div>` tag's background color is white.

```js
angular.module("Test", ["ngMaterial"]);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>



<body ng-app="Test" style="background-color: red;">
  {{1+1}}
  <div style="margin-top: 700px;">
    bar
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to know why this is happening and how would I be able to prevent this without explicitly assigning a background color to `<div>` tag.

Comment: you want to still have it in red after injecting ngMaterial?

Comment: Hi maik, I love white and red. haha

Comment: @Sajeetharan Correct. But of course without adding a background-color to `<div>` tag explicitly. It's bothering me that with the injection of ngMaterial renders the `<div>` tag with no background-color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because Angular material uses its own default theme. i.e,
primary - indigo
accent - pink
warn - red
background - white

So either you can change theme colors or inform material not to use its default theme:

```
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
     $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
     .backgroundPalette('Red')
});
```

OR

```
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
      $mdThemingProvider.disableTheming();
 });
```

```js
 var myApp = angular.module('Test', ['ngMaterial']);
       myApp.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
            $mdThemingProvider.disableTheming();
        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>



<body ng-app="Test" style="background-color: red;">
  {{1+1}}
  <div style="margin-top: 700px;">
    bar
  </div>
</body>
```